# Taken two pages back since render function is called twice

Tags: react-router, apollo-client

I want to go back to the previous page when Apollo Client error.graphQLErrors has an error with a specific message from the back-end server,
Below is the snippet of my code.

```
const Detail = () => { const { snackbar } = useSnackbar();
const history = useHistory();
        return(
        <Compo query={graphQLQuery}>
    {({ data, error,  }) => {
        if(error?.graphQLErrors[0]?.extensions?.debugMessage.includes('Specific Error')){
                        history.goBack();
                        snackbar('Specific Error');
                        return <></>;
        }
        else{
        //render another component
        }
    }
  }
        </Compo>);
```

Issue is since the render is called twice, when the error happens, `history.goBack()` is executed twice and I'm taken two pages back.
I'm able to avoid this by removing `<React.StrictMode>` encapsulating `<App>` component.
Is there a better way to do this?
I'm trying to avoid removing `<React.StrictMode>` since it's been there since a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are issuing an unintentional side-effect from the render method. In React function components the ***entire*** function body is considered to be the "render" method. Move all side-effects into a `useEffect` hook.

## Solution

Since the code is using a `children` function prop you'll need to abstract what the "child" is rendering into a React component that can use React hooks.

Example:

```
const DetailChild = ({ data, error }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { snackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const isErrorCondition = error?.graphQLErrors[0]?.extensions?.debugMessage.includes('Specific Error'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isErrorCondition)) {
      history.goBack();
      snackbar('Specific Error');
    }
  }, [error]);

  return isErrorCondition
    ? null
    : (
      ... render another component ...
    );
};
```

...

```
const Detail = () => {
  return (
    <Compo query={graphQLQuery}>
      {({ data, error }) => <DetailChild {...{ data, error }} />}
    </Compo>
  );
};
```